# Boost.Serialization Warning

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, boost-serialization

Not sure what is causing the following warning which, as I read, can be safely ignored 32 bit:

```
conversion from 'std::streamsize' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
```

I am performing routine Boost serialization and the program is working great.  The only problem is the compiler has a problem around the following code:

```
while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load_binary(void *,size_t)'
```

Any idea what is up with this?

Answer (score 1):

[std::streamsize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize) is a signed integral type. [size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is the unsigned integer type.

That's an unsafe conversion because it may cause data loss.
The compiler detects an unsafe conversion and issues a warning.